# c# application won't start in windows xp

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp

I've made c# application in VS 2010 and Windows 7 OS and used .Net 2.0 but when I tried to run it under Windows xp service pack 3 it won't start. There is no error, nothing is happening. Windows xp has .Net 3.5 installed. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Event log?

Comment: Looked in the event viewer (run eventvwr.msc) ?

Comment: In two months, this question will be on par with asking how to get your code working on Windows ME. XP is not currently a good target system.

Comment: @Magus This is not relevant - obviously, user2081328 runs into it now. In two months will be different day.

Comment: Definitely sounds like either a missing dependency or permissions... check the event log.

Comment: @T.S. That depends entirely on whether or not he can get the application feature complete and working on XP in less than two months. If he can't, then it's a bad target now. Even then, it smacks of wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some icon in project larger then 32x32. Just solved my problem deleting icon.